# Make overlay display once per session using html and java script

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have a code like below where, I want to display the overlay on website only once. This should automatically expire is executed once.

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    #boxoverlay{
        position:fixed;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
        z-index:555;
        display:none;
    }
   </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='boxoverlay'></div>
</body>
     <script type = "text/javascript">

        var popupState=document.cookie.indexOf('name=');
        if(popupState!=0){          
            document.cookie = "name=opened";
            document.getElementById("boxoverlay").style.display='block';
            hidepopup();
        }
        function hidepopup(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                document.getElementById("boxoverlay").style.display='none';
            },5000)
        }

  </script>
</html>
```

I'm struggling with the script code where it should not display the overlay again. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add some variable "indicator" which has true/false according to its event. Then - while script is executed check value of this variable

Comment: So you only want it to show up once? If the user goes off the page and back on should they still not see it then again?

Comment: yes Daniel, now the overlay shows continuously with my script, every time i refresh the page. I need it to display once per session. Means even if I open in a new tab it should not open once loaded. Unless opened in a private browsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `if(popupState!=0){` to `if(popupState<0){`. If `name=` is not found in the cookie string, `indexOf` will return `-1`. You create the cookie and show the overlay. If the cookie DOES exist, it might be placed behind a bunch of other cookies. In my case, the index was `298`. You want to check for any index 0 or greater.